# Chrome Extension, Service Worker, Web Requests

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

Does anyone know if it is possible to view web requests served from a Service Worker's cache with Chrome Extension APIs?

At the moment, it looks like web requests served from a Service Worker are much like requests served from the browser's cache - they are effectively invisible to the Chrome web request API.

I can use a content script in the page to read the navigator.serviceWorker. Maybe I could then clear the Service Worker's cache to ensure that the web requests were then fetched externally...